# Update the Progress Bar in the ListView when downloading

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have an Activity that show a list of database records . 
In this activity there is a custom ListView.
In the custom ListView, there is a Button and a TextView and a ProgressBar .
My button listener that call AsyncTask is in CustomAdapter class .

```
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(getContext());
                downloadTask.execute(url[position].toString());
```

AsynkTask work great .
But I want to update the Progress Bar during download process.
I've searched the Internet for three days but were unsuccessful.
I'm sorry for my English

```
public class listanimals extends ActionBarActivity {
private MyDatabase MyDataBase;
String[]  listurl;
ProgressBar progressBar;
TextView url2;
CustomList adapter;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private Context context;
    int myProgress;
    public DownloadTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {

        InputStream input = null;
        final GlobalClass caches = (GlobalClass) context.getApplicationContext();
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }


            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+caches.getName_cach()+".mp3");

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                myProgress = (int)(total*100/connection.getContentLength());

                output.write(data, 0, count);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
     //MY PROBLEM MAY HERE
        progressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        final GlobalClass caches = (GlobalClass) context.getApplicationContext();

        if (result != null)
            Toast.makeText(context,"Download error: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"File downloaded"+ "" + caches.getName_cach(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AsynkTask end
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listanimals);
    MyDataBase = new MyDatabase(this);
    final GlobalClass caches = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    final ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);


    SQLiteDatabase mydb = MyDataBase.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery("select * from animals", null);

    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
   final ArrayList<String> myListname = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> myListurl = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

            myList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            myListname.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")).trim());
            myListurl.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("url")));

            String[] listname = new String[myListname.size()];
            listname = myListname.toArray(listname);

            listurl = new String[myListurl.size()];
            listurl = myListurl.toArray(listurl);

            String[] listid = new String[myList.size()];
            listid = myList.toArray(listid);

             adapter = new
                    CustomList(listanimals.this, listname,listurl);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

   }}  finally{
        mydb.close();
    }}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private MyDatabase MyDataBase;

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final String[] url;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] web,String[] url) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_file, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.url = url;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final GlobalClass caches = (GlobalClass) context.getApplicationContext();

        MyDataBase = new MyDatabase(getContext());

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_file, null, true);
        Typeface kamran= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "IranNastaliq.ttf");
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)rowView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        TextView txtTitle3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        txtTitle3.setTypeface(kamran);
        url2=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        url2.setText(url[position]);
        txtTitle3.setText(web[position]);
        Button download=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.button);



        download.setTag(position);// Any data associated with the button has to be added with          setTag()

        download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {/////////call AsynkTask
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            caches.setName_cach(web[position]);
                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(getContext());
                downloadTask.execute(url[position].toString());


            }
        });

        return rowView;

     }


 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call publishProgress from the doInBackground method to update the ProgressBar: [publishProgress docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...))

This will call onProgressUpdate(Integer... values);

You don't need the myProgress instance variable;

Comment: Please mark as the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you Bro.I tried it . But this method works when the Progress Bar is in Activity. When Progress Bar is in custom List layout, that don't work. What is the solution?

Comment: @AmirGheybi Your ProgressBar is an instance variable of the class listAnimals. It should be instantiated in the onCreate method of that class.

Comment: I was crazy. Four days to do it, but I was not . can you make necessary change in my code?  thank you

Comment: @AmirGheybi I won't write your code for you, but there's a pretty good example in the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HDr9FdGIVg&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hmkEaYIvLLm5IEGM0kpwU&index=17

You need to call -  publishProgress((int) total*100/connection.getContentLength());

in the while loop
to update your progressbar.Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Bro.Video was pretty good . I tried it . But this method works when the Progress Bar is in Activity. When Progress Bar is in custom List layout, that don't work. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have a progress bar in each item of the list, while you keep a single instance in the activity. This means your progress view will point to the one in the last list item that the system asked you to draw. Which might not be the one from the list item you pressed the button for. I suggest you split the classes (take them out from the activity) and you'll better see your problem. But this is going to be only the first of your problems - because you launch the async task and in the meantime you can scroll that item off screen.